# SSRS Printer pop up not showing in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, printing, ssrs-2008-r2, windows-server-2012

I cannot get SSRS base report print pop up in Internet Explorer 11. But it successfully worked with ie 8.. Server os is 2012, SQL version is 2008 R2, client Pc is windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some older versions of SSRS you have to put IE in compatibility mode to get some of the features to work. You have two options, you can fix it client side or server side.

**Client Side: Fix the SSRS Compatibility Issue in IE 11**

This has to be applied to all users' browsers.

- Open the IE11 browser
- Press F12 – which would open a developer tool at the bottom of the
  browser
- Click "Emulation" tab
- Change the "Document mode" to "Edge"
- Try to access the report. You should now be able to access the report
  in IE11 without any issues.

**Server Side: Fix the SSRS Compatibility Issue at the Server Level**

This change will reflect in all users' browsers, you don't need to make any changes for the client browser settings.

- It is recommended to take a backup of the reportviewer.aspx file
  located at \Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting
  Services\ReportServer\Pages.
- Open the reportviewer.aspx file located in \Microsoft SQL
  Server\MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\Pages in
  notepad.
- Change the meta tag from `meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
  content="IE=5"` to `meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
  content="IE=Edge"`
- Save the file and try to access the report in IE11, you should now be
  able to access the report without any issues.

This exact issue is described in this [blog post](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3666/sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-is-not-compatible-with-internet-explorer-11/).

Comment: Changed IE11 settings. Compatibility settings, Active x settings and all related to generate. But error occurs client side printer could not load. How ever ill try 2nd option also.